# user input for string

Tags: c++, string

I got a program that standard uses a value for the string.
How can i change it so the user can input the value?

Best Regards

Joriek

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

std::string id_strnormal = "4a";
std::string code = "10 4a 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 10 03";

std::string start_str = code.substr(0, 2);
std::string id_str = code.substr(3, 2);

int str_length = code.length();
std::string stop_str = code.substr(str_length-5);


if (id_str == id_strnormal)
{
          std::cout << code << std::endl;
}
if (id_str != id_strnormal)
{
     std::cout << "package id isn't 4a" << std::endl;
} 
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you defeating the purpose of adding `using namespace std;` in your code? ^^

Comment: you can take any basic c++ book and read through or google to find the answer! this is a very basic question

Answer (score 1):

You can use : getline (cin , string) for user input. If user's input will be 4a asd , std::cin will not work, but the exemple from above will work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`std::cin`](http://cpp-tutorial.cpp4u.com/basics_io.html) for handling standard input.

Answer (score 0):

By using `cin>>input`
eg:

```
std::cin>>id_strnormal;  //instead of id_strnormal = "4a";
```